# Defeating ROP attacks in x86

Tags: attack-prevention, random, defense, memory, x86

Most defense techniques against [ROP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return-oriented_programming) revolves around randomization, such as [ASLR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization).

If I mark all regions of memory, other than the code segment, non-executable, will this defeat ROP?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No. Actually, most RoP attacks make use of existing codes (former return-into-libc-attacks). So, the RoP gadgets are snippets of existing code and have to be executable.